# Moving items in HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, html-table

I'm creating a stack-type table, therefore I want each data item to be moved down a row, and the new data is added to the top.

JavaScript

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            var start[] = document.getElementById("coinhistory").rows[i].cells;
            var destination = document.getElementById("coinhistory").rows[i++].cells;
            destination[x].innerHTML = document.getElementById("coinhistory").rows[i].cells;
        }
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="coinhistory">
    <tr>
        <th>Game Number</th>
        <th>Outcome</th>
        <th>Choice</th>
        <th>Balance Change</th>
        <th>Generated Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>example1</td>
        <td>example1</td>
        <td>example1</td>
        <td>example1</td>
        <td>example1</td>
    <tr> //repeated for 10
```

This is what I have so far, I want each item to be moved down once in it's own row. If you want more code or anything else please say. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insertRow(position)` to insert a row at a specified position, and then add cells to the row you create.  Here is an example where a row is added in the first position:

```js
var addRowToTop = (arr) => {
  let table = document.getElementById("coinhistory");
  let row = table.insertRow(1); // insert a new row right under the table headers
  let cells = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let temp = row.insertCell(i);
    temp.innerHTML = arr[i];
  }
}

addRowToTop(["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"])
addRowToTop(["this", "one", "above", "last", "one"])
```

```html
<table id="coinhistory">
  <tr>
    <th>Game Number</th>
    <th>Outcome</th>
    <th>Choice</th>
    <th>Balance Change</th>
    <th>Generated Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Was really overthinking this, thanks very much. I'll get to work on deleting the last row. As it's a set location, shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @SubZeroFish Glad to help! If this answered your question, take a look at [What to do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use JavaScript Array `push()` Method ?

because 
`push()` method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

**Tip:** To add items at the beginning of an array, use the `unshift()` method

Comment: I thought I was missing out on some useful java methods. I'll use them to help delete the last row :)

Comment: @SubZeroFish How would unshift allow you to delete the last row? Use `array.slice()` to delete rows.